# How can I parse json array in python?

Tags: python, shell, apache-pig

```
[
    {
        "key": "abc123",
        "columns": [
            [
                "2015-08-05 12\\:38\\:02+0000:",
                "",
                1439565881058000
            ],
            [
                "2015-08-05 12\\:38\\:02+0000:type",
                "1",
                1439565881058000
            ],
            [
                "2015-08-05 12\\:38\\:02+0000:duration",
                "21",
                1439565881058000
            ],
            [
                "2015-08-05 12\\:38\\:02+0000:first_name",
                "abc",
                1439565881058000
            ],
            [
                "2015-08-05 12\\:38\\:02+0000:last_name",
                "xyz",
                1439565881058000
            ],
            [
                "2015-08-05 12\\:38\\:02+0000:number",
                "012456789",
                1439565881058000
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're more likely to get helpful answers if your question is about a specific problem, rather than something generic.

Answer (score 1):

use json library

```
data = json.loads(your_jsondata)
```

you can access your json data by calling it like

```
data[0]['key']
```

to get key

Comment: I have done as above mentioned but still I am getting below error >>> import json
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> 
>>> with open('/Users/xxx/Documents/sample.json') as data_file:    
...     data = json.load(data_file)
... 
>>> data['key']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @SarthakPrakash what you have is an array so you should call it like data[0]['key']

Comment: Thanks ! What I have to do for extract column values ??

Comment: @SarthakPrakash just use columns instead of key and you get array of columns data[0]['columns']